# Passing parameters from main report to subreport in Jasper

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I have a *JasperReport* where I am passing the report Date from a Main Report to a sub report. This works fine. I also have another where I am passing the same parameter to a sub report that has multiple SubReports. When I preview it in *Ireports* all the pages for it appear blank which means the sub-sub reports are being called but the report Date is not being passed as all the sub-sub report SQL are conditioned on the report Date. How can I get the report Date field to the sub sub reports? When I preview the SubReport and type in the report Date all the report dates work all four pages are populated with the correct data.

Answer (score 48):

Follow the steps below to pass parameters into subreports:

1. Create main report parameter, such as `DATE_PARAM`.
2. Open sub report and Create a parameter with the same name and the same type.
3. Go back to main report
4. Right-click on sub report, select properties
5. Choose parameter
6. Add parameter from main report to sub report with parameter name same parameter name

The parameter is passed from the main report to the subreport.

Comment: It didn't work. When I try to compile my sub report which contains the other sub report, it says: Unable to locate the subreport with expression: $P{'sub_sub_report_expression'}

Comment: Working on jaspersoft 6.9.0

Answer (score 21):

My guess is they are using a default value.

Assuming the name of the Parameter in the Main Report is `TEST_DATE` and the name in the Sub-report is `TEST_DATE2` then you need to add the following in between the opening and closing `subreport` elements in the XML:

```
<subreportParameter name="TEST_DATE2">
    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{TEST_DATE}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
</subreportParameter>
```

For the sake of completeness, here is an example that has a main report and a subreport, that should work by just changing the value for `SUBREPORT_DIR` to point to where you have them placed.

**report1.jrxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report1" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="7e2bc622-d768-437e-8c33-fc777bc06f8c">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <parameter name="TEST_DATE" class="java.util.Date"/>
    <parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["C:\\Reports\\"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="83" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="4a2cf434-4473-48db-a89f-17a19d25cc4c" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{TEST_DATE}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <subreport>
                <reportElement uuid="54c02e96-6d47-49db-9b9c-58e1dd153242" x="0" y="30" width="200" height="35"/>
                <subreportParameter name="TEST_DATE2">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{TEST_DATE}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "report1_subreport1.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
</jasperReport>
```

**report1_subreport1.jrxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report1_subreport1" language="groovy" pageWidth="200" pageHeight="35" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="200" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" uuid="3cedac90-63cb-43cb-9d0f-e401543e65dd">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <parameter name="TEST_DATE2" class="java.util.Date" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="ca7f3da6-79f0-4d95-92db-6c5dbf777df9" x="0" y="15" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{TEST_DATE2}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
</jasperReport>
```

Answer (score 12):

If you are using iReport to create reports then open the main report in iReport and select `Subreport` and go to the `property` section of the report, click on `Parameters` property and click on `Copy from master` tab. From there you can select the parameters which you want to pass to the sub report.