# Passing values from main report to subreport in JasperReports

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I have a simple select sql query with 2 parameters that I want it to be in my query text in main report. It returns about 100 values that I want to put in 10 subreports (10 values per subreport). On main report I need to display only one parameter. All the values from query I need to be in subreports. How do I pass them? 
Connection to database is returned to me from application, parameter values also. I'm using *iReport 4.7.0*.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JasperReports: How to pass parameter to subReport](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310188/jasperreports-how-to-pass-parameter-to-subreport) & [Passing parameters from main report to subreport to subreport in Jasper](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13843167/876298)

Comment: I need to send return values from query. Do I send them as parameters from main report(field from main = parameter in subreport) or can I define fields in subreports with the same name as they were returned from query from main report?

Comment: I don't need to pass parameters, I need to pass query result to subreport. All these suggestions are to pass parameters to subpreport. I don't need that. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Parameters are attached to the dataset, if you expand the dataset itself, you'll find a section there for parameters, just like in your main report.

You'll need to link the parameters together though, using the connection properties where you're actually using the dataset, eg, in a chart or a table. For example, in the table, you go to the dataset tab of the properties pane, and click on the parameters button to map the parameters between your main report and your sub dataset.

More [here](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/823038/passing-main-parameter-sub-datasets-jasperstudio).